# 'find' files or folders at any depth that match a regular expression and copy all to a single folder? (consolidate)

Tags: regex, bash, directory, find

How do I use the bash 'find' command to find all files *and* folders at any depth starting at a base folder that match a regular expression, then copy all matching files and folders to a single output folder?

Example, if I have the following directory tree:

```
# EXISTING/INPUT DIRECTORY TREE
./indir_a
  file_1.txt
  file_2.txt
./indir_b
  file_1.jpg
  file_2.jpg
./indir_c
  file_1.pdf
  file_2.pdf
./indir_1
  file_a
  file_b
  file_c
./indir_2
  file_e
  file_f
  file_g
```

how do I copy all files and folders that match "_1" (and "_2") such that I end up with an output folder tree like this?

```
# OUTPUT DIRECTORY TREE (copies only)
./outdir_1/
  file_1.txt
  file_1.jpg
  file_1.pdf
  file_a
  file_b
  file_c

./outdir_2/
  file_2.txt
  file_2.jpg
  file_2.pdf
  file_e
  file_f
  file_g
```

Thanks.

Comment: What would happen to files in directory `dir_1_2`? Or in the directory `dir_1/dir_2`? Or even, what would happen to the file `dir_1/file_2`? You need to think of it. In your title, you mention copying them all to a **single** folder. Your output does not agree with the title.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Based on your pattern, the assumption is the the regular expression matches at the end of the basename.  Correct?

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks, the real expression is longer and unique - this is just an example. Assume there is no "_1_2"

Comment: @RichardJessop The regular expression will match a sub-string anywhere in either a filename or a folder name in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and your title do not match.  But...

**Copy all matching files into a single directory**

```
find /source/path -type f -name "*something*" -exec /bin/mv {} /target/dir \; -print
```

Obviously if you have 2 files with the same name, only the second one will be in the target directory.

---

**If you need to copy the directory structure as well**

```
find /source/path -type f -name "*something*" -print >list_of_files.txt

tar -cvpf tocopy.tar -T list_of_files.txt
```

`-T FILE` is the same as `--files-from=FILE`.  It takes the files to add into the `tar` from FILE.

Then extract tocopy.tar into the /target/dir directory.

```
cd /target/dir
tar -xvpf tocopy.tar
```

This can be combined into a single `tar -c... | tar -x...`, but that is left as an exercise :-)

Comment: I tried to summarize the question to shorten the title, but I think it is saying the same thing. The example was to clarify, and thanks for your ideas.